# Как этот код можно упростить?

Tags: java, инспекция-кода, битовые-операции

```
public long getLong() {
    return (data.get(pointer++) & 0xFF) << 4 | (data.get(pointer++) & 0xFF) << 56
            | (data.get(pointer++) & 0xFF) << 48 | (data.get(pointer++) & 0xFF << 32)
            | (data.get(pointer++) & 0xFF) << 24 | (data.get(pointer++) & 0xFF) << 16
            | (data.get(pointer++) & 0xFF) << 8 | (data.get(pointer++) & 0xFF);
}
```

Поинтер тут для того, что бы следующий вызов метода `getLong()` читал далее байты, как это упростить?
Выходит, что мне нужно что-то на подобии DataInputStream, но с поинтером.

Comment: вместо << 4 имелось в виду  << 40?

Answer (score 2):

Например, так

```
public long getLong() {
  int[] shifts = {4, 56, 48, 32, 24, 16, 8, 0};
  long res = 0;
  for (int shift : shifts)
    res |= data.get(pointer++) & 0xFF) << shift;
  return res;
}
```